# Вот такая штука:

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
    $myatk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atk WHERE name='".$_GET['value']."' ");
    $atk = mysql_query($myatk);
    $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE       username='".$_SESSION['username']."' and start='$on'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql);
```

Вопрос как сделать вот так:

```
$uron = $row['$atk['type']'];
```

Comment: Скорее всего так `$uron = $row[$atk['type']];` но мне интересно где логика?

Comment: структуру таблиц в студию,
> $row['$atk['type']']; // это плохо! и ни разу неправильно.

Задача какая, вопрос правильно сформулируй.

Comment: Я делаю браузерную игру, и это часть боя, и есть два типа атаки, Спец.Атака и Физ.Атака, потом мы вытягиваем атаку которую использовал пользователем и смотрим, если это физ.атака , то отнимаем жизни бота со стата Физ.Атаки, а если пользователь использовал Спец.Атаку, то отнимаем жизни боту со стата Спец.Атаки , Стат - это показатель урона героя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myatk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atk WHERE name='".$_GET['value']."' ");
$atk = mysql_query($myatk);
```

чеэто вообще ?

```
$myatk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atk WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value'])."' ");
$atk = mysql_fetch_assoc($myatk);
$mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE       username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' and start='$on'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql);

$uron = $row[$atk['type']];
```

Comment: Не суть что прокатит, мы же 

>SELECT * FROM atk WHERE name='".$_GET['value']."' "

Выбираем все поля, и условия особого нет, не думаю что

>SELECT * FROM atk WHERE name='".$_GET['value']."' "

не выберет нам  1К одинаковых значений.

Comment: Просто я исправил 2 ошибки.

1. $atk = mysql_query($myatk); нужно $atk = mysql_fetch_assoc($myatk);
2. изменил фетч_аррэй на mysql_fetch_assoc (потому что фетч аррей возвращает массив с числовыми ключами)